# How can one insert an arrow on the z-axis of a ternary diagram to indicate increasing order of the element on this axis?

Tags: pgfplots, arrows

I need help on how I can insert `X_{Bi}` and a `rightarrow` on the z-axis of each of the `subfigures` in my ternary diagram. `X_{Bi}` implies `X` subscript `Bi` while `rightarrow` is as in LaTeX to indicate that `Bi` on the z-axis is increasing from left to right. In the example shown below I want to use a `rightarrow` placed in front or at the top of `X_{Bi}` to show that `X_{Bi}` is increasing from 0 to 1.0 in each of the two figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           no markers,
%           clip=false,
%         disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           xlabel=Sn,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sb,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
    ]

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
    };
  \end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{First Image}
\label{fig:a:first}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           no markers,
%           clip=false,
%         disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           xlabel=Sb,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sn,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
  ]

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
    };

\end{ternaryaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Second Image}
\label{fig:a:second}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Isoactivity curves}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your code to remove all parts that don't directly relate to the question? If I understand correctly, the example doesn't need three figures and there doesn't even need to be any data in the axes.

Comment: Thanks Jake.I have now edited both the question and the example as requested for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having being able to successfully positioned X_{Bi} along the z-axis by inserting `\node at (zticklabel cs:0.5) [anchor=north] {$X_{Bi}$}` before the line `\end{ternaryaxis}` in the code and `activate clip=false` in the code(as suggested today by Jake),I observed that by adding `$\rightarrow$` to the item in the last item in the `\node` line the expected result which answered this question was obtained.Thus, I now have the following result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           no markers,
           clip=false,
%         disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           xlabel=Sn,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sb,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
    ]

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
    };
\node at (zticklabel cs:0.5) [anchor=north] {$X_{Bi}$ $\rightarrow$ };
  \end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{First Image}
\label{fig:a:first}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           no markers,
          clip=false,
%         disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           xlabel=Sb,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sn,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
  ]

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
    };
\node at (zticklabel cs:0.5) [anchor=north] {$X_{Bi}$$\rightarrow$};
\end{ternaryaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Second Image}
\label{fig:a:second}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Isoactivity curves}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can format code samples by highlighting the code and clicking the `{}` button in the editor (or pressing Ctrl+K). That makes the post much easier to read.

Comment: Thanks Jake for this useful information on code formatting.